# How do I count occurrences of a property value in a collection?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some data that I arrange into a collection of custom class objects.

Each object has a couple of properties aside from its unique name, which I will refer to as `batch` and `exists`

There are many objects in my collection, but only a few possible values of `batch` (although the number of possibilities is not pre-defined).

What is the easiest way to count occurrences of each possible value of `batch`?

Ultimately I want to create a userform something like this (values are arbitrary, for illustration):

```
Batch A  25 parts  (2 missing)
Batch B  17 parts
Batch C  16 parts  (1 missing)
```

One of my ideas was to make a custom "batch" class, which would have properties `.count` and `.existcount` and create a collection of those objects.

I want to know if there is a simpler, more straightforward way to count these values.  Should I scrap the idea of a secondary collection and just create some loops and counter variables when I generate my userform?

Answer (score 0):

You described well the two possibilities that you have:

1. Loop over your collection every time you need the count
2. Precompute the statistics, and access it when needed

This is a common choice one often has to do. I think here it is between performance vs. complexity.

Option 1 with a naive loop implementation will take you an O(n) time, where n is the size of your collection. And, unless your collection is static, you will have to compute it everytime you need your statistics. On the bright side, the naive looping is fairly trivial to write. Performance on frequent queries and/or large collections could suffer.

Option 2 is fast for retrieval, O(1) basically. But everytime your collection changes, you need to recompute your statistics. However this is incremental recomputing, i.e. you do not have to go through the whole collection but just over the changed items. But that means you need to deal with all the possibilities of updates (new item, deleted item, updated items). So that's a bit more complex than the naive loop. Now if your collections are entirely new all the time, and you query them only once, you have little to gain here.

So up to you to decide where to tradeoff according to the parameters of your problems.